# Finding unique sets without subsets in python array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matching

I have a dataset that needs to output boolean style data, just 1 and 0, for true or not true. I am trying to parse simple data sets I've processed to look for a subset of information in a numpy array, the array is about 100,000 elements in one direction and 20 in the other. I only need to search along the 20 axis, but I need to do that for each of the 100,000 entries and get output that I can map.

I've produced an array of this size made up of zeros, with the intention to simply mark the matching index indicator to a 1. A main hitch is that if I find a long set (I'm working with long sets to small sets), I need to NOT include any smaller set that's within it.

Sample:
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1]

I need to find here that there are 1 group of 5, starting at index 2, and 1 group of 3, starting at index 9, and not return any subset of the group of 5 as though it were a group of 4 or a group of 3, thus leaving the results for all those already covered values. i.e. for groups of 3, the indices 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 would all remain zero. It doesn't need to be overly efficient, I don't care if it searches anyways, I just need to not keep the result.

Currently I'm using a codeblock basically like this for a simple search:

```
values = numpy.array([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1])
searchval = [1,2]
N = len(searchval)
possibles = numpy.where(values == searchval[0])[0]
print(possibles)
solns = []
for p in possibles:
    check = values[p:p+N]
    if numpy.all(check == searchval):
        solns.append(p)
print(solns)
```

I've been wracking my brain trying to come up with a way to restructure this or similar code to produce the desires results. The end goal is to be searching for groups of 9 down to groups of 3, and having effectively a matrix of 1s and 0s indicating if an index has a group starting on it that is as long as we want.

Hopefully someone can point me to what I'm missing to make this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools), a third-party library (`pip install more_itertools`):

```
import more_itertools as mit


sample = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

groups = [list(c) for c in mit.consecutive_groups((mit.locate(sample)))]
d = {group[0]: len(group) for group in groups}
d
# {2: 5, 9: 3, 15: 1, 17: 1}
```

This result reads "At index `2` is a group of 5 ones.  At group `9` is a group of 3 ones," etc.

---

*Details*

- [`more_itertools.locate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.locate) finds indices for truthy items by default.
- [`more_itertools.consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups) chunks consecutive numbers together.
- The result is a dictionary of (starting-index, length) pairs.

As a [dictionary](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary), you can extract different kinds of information:

```
>>> # List of starting indices
>>> list(d)
[2, 9, 15, 17]

>>> # List indices for all lonely groups
>>> [k for k, v in d.items() if v == 1]
[15, 17]

>>> # List indices of groups greater the 2 items
>>> [k for k, v in d.items() if v > 1]
[2, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful! Worked well once I incorporated it into my code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
from collections import defaultdict

sample = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

# Keys are number of consecutive 1's, values are indicies
results = defaultdict(list)
found = 0

for i, x in enumerate(samples):
    if x == 1:
        found += 1
    elif i == 0 or found == 0:
        continue
    else:
        results[found].append(i - found)
        found = 0

if found:
    results[found].append(i - found + 1)

assert results == {1: [15, 17], 3: [9], 5: [2]}
```

Comment: I'm not experienced with dictionaries. How can I pull these out by their key. If I make it a list I just get 1, 3, 5 from this example. But to get it into my matrix I need to loop through the values by their numerical values. Could you offer a bit of clarification on the extraction? Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

If you want all indicies for items that had 3 repetitive values of 1, can get that by doing: indicies = results[3]

Comment: This method seems to work pretty well, except for one issue. If the group of any length, for instance 1 or 3, is at the end of the list, i.e. one of the 1s in the group is the last element, it reports the wrong index, it tells me it's one index sooner than it is. 

So if I take the list you generated and move that last #1 back, it correctly tells me it is index 16, but in reality, it's index 17 now, and is saying it's index 17. Not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a numpy solution. I'm using a small example for demonstration but it easily scales (`20 x 100,000` takes 25 ms on my rather modest laptop, see timings at the end of this post):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> 
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (5, 10), dtype=np.int8)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
>>> 
>>> padded = np.pad(a,((1,1),(0,0)), 'constant')
# compare array to itself with offset to mark all switches from
# 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0
# then use 'where' to extract the coordinates
>>> colinds, rowinds = np.where((padded[:-1] != padded[1:]).T)
>>> 
# the lengths of sets are the differences between switch points
>>> lengths = rowinds[1::2] - rowinds[::2]
# now we have the lengths we are free to throw the off-switches away
>>> colinds, rowinds = colinds[::2], rowinds[::2]
>>> 
# admire
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(zip(colinds, rowinds, lengths)))
[(0, 2, 1),
 (1, 0, 2),
 (2, 1, 2),
 (2, 4, 1),
 (3, 2, 1),
 (4, 0, 5),
 (5, 0, 1),
 (5, 2, 1),
 (5, 4, 1),
 (6, 1, 1),
 (6, 3, 2),
 (7, 4, 1)]
```

Timings:

```
>>> def find_stretches(a):
...     padded = np.pad(a,((1,1),(0,0)), 'constant')
...     colinds, rowinds = np.where((padded[:-1] != padded[1:]).T)
...     lengths = rowinds[1::2] - rowinds[::2]
...     colinds, rowinds = colinds[::2], rowinds[::2]
...     return colinds, rowinds, lengths
... 
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (20, 100000), dtype=np.int8)
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=100)
>>> repeat('find_stretches(a)', **kwds)
[2.475784719004878, 2.4715258619980887, 2.4705517270049313]
```